# Why does dynamic page shows the same data per request in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have a dynamic page named `[className].js`. In it, I'm trying the fetch the data using getServerSideProps. Currently, I have only two sets of data. When I click a link, that's supposed to take me the dynamic page with the className and show the data within it. But, no matter which link I click, it always shows the data of the first one.

Why is this happening? How can I get the data of the specified className?

```
export default function classPage({ classDetail }) {
  const capitalizedClassTitle =
    classDetail.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + classDetail.title.slice(1);
  const classTitle = capitalizedClassTitle.replace(/-/g, " ");

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <div>This is the page for {classTitle}</div>
      <div className="w-20 h-20">
        <Image
          src={classDetail.classImageURL}
          width={classDetail.imageWidth}
          height={classDetail.imageHeight}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { className } }) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/admin/classes/${className}`
  );
  const { data } = await res.json();

  return { props: { classDetail: data } };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In the api pages of [className], I had this line of code wrong.

```
const classDetail = await Class.findOne({className});
```

I changed it to `await Class.findOne({title: className})` and now it is working as I wished. `title` was the keyword for className in my Class schema.